# Css em todas as divs geradas por php/mysql

Tags: jquery

Como fazer para quando o mouse entra na div ele aumenta a opacity para 1.0 e quando sai da div volta pra opacity anterior

Exemplo:

PHP/MYSQL

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bd) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "
<table border=0 width=\"720\">
<tr id=\"div\">
<td width=\"382\">
TEXTO
</td> 
</tr></table><br><br>";
}
```

JS

```
<script>
$("#div").mouseover(function() {
$("#div").css("opacity","1.0");
});

$("#div").mouseout(function() {
$("#div").css("opacity","0.8");
});
</script>
```

na segunda div vinda do db o js não funciona, só na primeira. tentei

```
<script>
$("#div").mouseover(function() {
$("#div").next().css("opacity","1.0");
});
</script>
```

mas não funcionou...aguardo...

Comment: Nunca use o mesmo ***id*** para mais de um elemento , ***id***'s são únicos

Comment: Viu o meu edit na resposta sobre delegar eventos? testou isso?

Answer (score 4):

Para adicionar CSS a elementos gerados dinamicamente têm duas opções:

**#1** - dar uma classe a esse elemento e adicionar as regras dessa classe no seu CSS

Assim no PHP adiciona a classe newElement

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "
    <table border=0 width=\"720\">
        <tr id=\"div\" class=\"newElement\">
            <td width=\"382\">
                TEXTO
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </table><br><br>";
}
```

e no CSS: `.newElement{ opacity: 1;}`

**#2** - correr o código que usou em cima logo depois de os elementos terem sido adicionados, ie dentro da função onSuccess do ajax

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#esteID").css("opacity","1.0");
    // ou então no elemento parente comum: $("#parente div").css("opacity","1.0");
}
```

**Nota:** os ID's têm de ser únicos. No seu `while` no PHP dá ideia que está a usar o mesmo ID. Isso dá erros no código, o mais comum é uma regra ser só aplicada ao primeiro elemento que tem a ID que pretende. Se quer usar as mesmas regras em vários elementos, então use `class`. Se pretende gerar IDs dinamicamente dentro do seu `while` pode adicionar um contador que acrescenta um numero extra no seu ID. Mas para lhe dar um exemplo exato preciso saber melhor como usa o ajax.

---

### EDIT:

Depois de ter visto a sua resposta percebí que a perunta estava mal feita (agora corrigida) e que o que você precisa é usar delegação de eventos pois o event handler foi corrido antes de o html estar na página. Então use assim:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.div', function () {
    $(this).css("opacity", 1);
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.div', function () {
    $(this).css("opacity", "0.8");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui assim:

PHP

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bd) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "
<table border=0 width=\"720\">
<tr id=\"div\" class=\"div\">
<td width=\"382\">
TEXTO
</td> 
</tr></table><br><br>";
}
```

JS

```
$(".div").mouseover(function() {
$(this).css("opacity","1.0").next(".div").css("opacity","1.0");
});

$(".div").mouseout(function() {
$(this).css("opacity","0.8").next(".div").css("opacity","0.8");
});
```

Usando o css(), next() depois o css() de novo...

OU usando CSS somente:

```
#div {
opacity: 0.8;
}

#div:hover {
opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, então deu uma classe como eu sugerí, mas a própria ação de adicionar o CSS tem de ser feito manualmente com um mouseover? era isso que pretendia? E já agora, continua a ter ID's duplicados.

Comment: O id duplicado não é problema, eu podia ter feito com css também, exemplo: .div:hover { opacity: 1.0; }

Comment: Asua pergunta foi: `Como adicionar css em todas as divs vindas do php/mysql ?` Não vejo como a sua resposta soluciona o problema de maneira eficaz. Ou a pergunta está mal feita/incompleta ou a sua resposta está. O problema de IDs duplicadas deve de ser resolvido.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta foi mal feita, eu queria simplesmente quando o mouse entra na div ele aumenta a opacity para 1.0 e quando sai da div volta pra opacity anterior...

Comment: na verdade sabia a resposta, é que tinha esquecido o básico mas já lembrei :)

Comment: OK, editei a minha resposta com a solução para o seu problema. Você tem de usar delegação de eventos e a ideia das classes.

Comment: obrigado @Sergio, editei a pergunta também...